# Symfony - using column in unquoted mapping value is deprecated

Tags: php, exception, yaml, parseexception

I am configuring my security.yml file and adding new link that will throw an ParseException with my Symofny 3.0.

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/download/thing/{hash}, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY]}
```

The problem seems to be with {hash} part?

Comment: Did you try quoting it like the message implies you should (`path: "^/download/thing/{hash}"`)?

Comment: Url that starts with `/download/thing/` already includes `hash`

Comment: I am just not sure if that solution would work. @flyx

Comment: - { path: ^/download/thing/}, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY]} You imply this would work event when setting route like * @Route("/download/thing/{hash}", name="thing_download") @u_mulder

Comment: Access control does not care about routing. it checks current path according to list of paths in a config.

Comment: Paths like `/download/thing/42`, `/download/thing/stuff`, `/download/thing/some-hash-here` will be processed by this rule.